# R: How create a edgelist out of a dataframe with many empty/blank fields?

Tags: r, edge-list

I need an edgelist for an network analisys. My Dataset is an big .csv file with 56400 rows an 1330 columns, but most fields are empty/blank. To create the edgelist I wannt to combine the fields from my data set to a data fram with 2 columns and X rows. My code:

```
#read my dataset
mydf <- read.csv("....\\clean5.csv",
                 header = TRUE, sep = ";", encoding = "UTF-8")

#creating a edgelist without blank fields
edgelist <- testdf %>% 
  apply(., 1, function(.x){   
    .x[!is.na(.x)] %>%        
      combn(2) %>%             
      t() %>%                
      as.data.frame()         
  }) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .)
```

My Problem: My code cant detect witch fields are empty/blank, so most fields in my edgelist are combinations with blank fields ... and thats makes the edgelist way too big. All fields have the datatyp "character", I think thats my problem ... but I cant solv it.

I tryed to transforming all blank fields to NA, so that my code can detect. The datatyp dosent change from character to logic, so the fields become `<NA>` and not "real" `NA`. I searched for solutions, but nothing worked for me.

Dose someone has an idea? I'm very thankful for every suport :)

**Update:**

Here is a dput() from a small part of my data:

```
test <- 
structure(list(
X1 = c("A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A "),
X2 = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
X3 = c("", "C ", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", "C "),
X4 = c("", "", "D", "", "", "", "D", "", "", "", "D", "", "", "", "D", "", "", "", "D", ""),
X5 = c("", "", "E ", "", "", "", "E ", "", "", "", "E ", "", "", "", "E ", "", "", "", "E ", ""),
X6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
X7 = c("", "", "G ", "", "", "", "G ", "", "", "", "G ", "", "", "", "G ", "", "", "", "G ", ""),
X8 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "", ""),
X9 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "", ""),
X10 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", ""),
X11 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "D", "", "", "", "", ""),
X12 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "E ", "", "", "", "", ""),
X13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
X14 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "G ", "", "", "", "", ""),
X15 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "", ""),
X16 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "", ""),
X17 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", "C ", "", ""),
X18 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "D", "", "", "", "", ""),
X19 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "E ", "", "", "", "", ""),
X20 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please include a small example of what your data looks like, either using dput() or a built-in data set? It would make it possible for us to run your code - it's difficult to help when we can't run your example. For creating things like edge lists, I'd generally recommend having a look at the {igraph} package.

Comment: @nrennie sorry, I'm a newbie ... how to sent a dataset in here?

Comment: Either find a built-in data set that looks similar to your input and tell us what it is and which package it comes from, or include some data (either real if you're allowed to share it, or some synthetic data you've created) - use `dput()` on the data in R, and paste the output from `dput()` in your question.

Comment: Please update the question to include the data - it's much easier for people to help if you include (a small part of) it via `dput()` instead of via a link. In your example code, where you have `testdf` - is this supposed to be `mydf` or is it a different object?